# Deploy project in Google app engine using command prompt

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, command-prompt

How do you deploy a project in Google App Engine using Eclipse? Is there a reference for the command line options required? Can it even be automated into a single action for the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 1):

using Java `appcfg update war`
for python `appcfg.py update <appdir>`